# Protractor stopped clicking on the buttons throughout the site

Tags: protractor

On the project recently began the Angular upgrade process. The app is now running in “hybrid” mode with both AngularJS 1.5 and Angular 6.0. and the protractor stopped clicking on the buttons throughout the site. How can I solve this problem on my part?

utils.click(by.id('some id'));(does not click)
element(by.id('some id')).click();(does not click)
Also with css xpath...

I try click:
element(by.xpath('//a/span[contains(text(),"Build")]/..')).click();

HTML:

```
<a href="#" uib-dropdown-toggle="" class="lg-main-nav__item-link dropdown-toggle" ng-class="{'active': navTab.active}" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa lg-main-nav__item-icon fa-puzzle-piece" ng-class="navTab.icon"></i>
            <span ng-bind="navTab.label" class="ng-binding">Build</span>
          </a>
```

Webstorm report:

```
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
```

Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:4281:23)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)

Comment: If you click it manually, is it clickable? Also please add the HTML and format your question.

Comment: Can you please share the error message as well, Also include the html file along with code which was working before.

Comment: I'm having the same exact trouble.  Clicking manually works.  I feel like it's an error in the way that we've bootstrapped things